# Printing a 2D numpy array not, showing float values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, precision

I am trying to display a 2D numpy array of floats but whenever I print, the array is only printed as whole numbers. Is there any way I can display the full float?

I know I can get rid of np.array but I want the array to be displayed vertically.

```
import numpy as np

MPass = 100
MPL = 25
ME = 120
Mwob = ME + MPL + MPass
rho = 1.225
g = 9.8
R = 0.3
pi = 3.14159
A = pi * R** 2
Aduct = 1.5 * A
Wwob = Mwob * g
Mb = 300
e = 400
Nfan = 12
w, h = 4, 101
X = np.array([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)])
x = 0

while Mb < 401:
    Wb = Mb * g
    Wt = Wb + Wwob
    Mt = Mb + Mwob
    Pav = e * Mb
    Pav_fan = Pav/Nfan
    vi = (Pav_fan/(2*rho*Aduct))**(1/3)
    Tmax_fan = 2 * rho * Aduct * vi**2
    Ttmax = Tmax_fan * Nfan
    Fnet = Ttmax - Wt
    X[x][0] = Mb
    X[x][1] = Fnet
    X[x][2] = Mt
    a = Fnet/Mt
    if a < 0:
        t = 0
    else:
        t = ((2*762)/a)**0.5
    X[x][3] = t
    x = x + 1
    Mb = Mb + 1

print(X)
```

Comment: Check the type of np array you have. It could be defined as containing ints

Comment: By the way this is too much code. See [example]

Comment: [python - I am try to assigne float numbers from tuple to numpy array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300414/i-am-try-to-assigne-float-numbers-from-tuple-to-numpy-array) (although that old question is quite poorly worded and also not have a [example])

Comment: try `X=np.zeros((h, w))`  Creating it with all `0` makes a `int` dtype array.  You don't want that.  Learn what the basic properties of a array mean, `shape` and `dtype`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the

```
X = np.array([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)])
```

to

```
X = np.array([[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)], dtype=float)
```

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: or use `0.` instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

you can try just casting the float: `print(np.array(X,dtype=float))`

Comment: convert the dtype before assigning values.